# Swift binary operator for protocols that returns the receiver type (which conforms to the Protocol)

Tags: swift, swift2, binary-operators, dynamictype

For Friday Fun, I wanted to model Angles in interchangable formats. I'm not sure if I've done it in the most Swift idiomatic way, but I'm learning. So I have an `Angle` protocol, and then 3 different struct types (Radians, Degrees, and Rotations) which all conform to the Angle protocol. I'd like to be able to add/subtract them, but the trick is, I want the `lhs` argument to dictate the return type. For example:

```
Degrees(180) + Rotations(0.25) --> Degrees(270)
```

or

```
Rotations(0.25) + Radians(M_PI) -> Rotations(0.75)
```

What I was hoping was I could do something like

```
func + (lhs:Angle, rhs:Angle) -> Angle {
    return lhs.dynamicType(rawRadians: lhs.rawRadians + rhs.rawRadians)
}
```

The `Angle` protocol requires a `var rawRadians:CGFloat { get }` as well as an `init(rawRadians:CGFloat)`

I could do this with a Smalltalk-esque double dispatch approach, but I think there most be a more Swift appropriate approach (especially one that requires less code, double dispatch requires a lot of boilerplate code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a generic addition:

```
func +<A: Angle>(lhs: A, rhs: Angle) -> A {
    return A(rawRadians: lhs.rawRadians + rhs.rawRadians)
}
```

This way the addition will return whatever type is on the lhs.

Generally speaking, if you're using `dynamicType`, you're probably fighting Swift. Swift relies more on generics and protocols (i.e. static type information at compile time) rather than dynamic dispatch (i.e dynamic type information at runtime).

In this code, as you say, `A` is a placeholder for "some type, that conforms to `Angle`, to be determined at compile time." So in your first example:

```
Degrees(180) + Rotations(0.25) --> Degrees(270)
```

This actually calls a specialized function `+<Degrees>`. And this:

```
Rotations(0.25) + Radians(M_PI) -> Rotations(0.75)
```

calls a (logically) different function called `+<Rotations>`. The compiler may choose to optimize these functions into a single function, but logically they are independent functions, created at compile time. It's basically a shortcut for writing `addDegrees(Degrees, Angle)` and `addRotations(Rotations, Angle)` by hand.

Now, to your question about a function that takes two Angles and returns.... well, what? If you want to return an `Angle` in this case, that's easy, and exactly matches your original signature:

```
func +(lhs: Angle, rhs: Angle) -> Angle {
    return Radians(rawRadians: lhs.rawRadians + rhs.rawRadians)
}
```

"But..." you're saying, "that returns `Radians`." No it doesn't. It returns `Angle`. You can do anything "angle-like" on it you want. The implementation details are opaque as they should be. If you care that the underlying data structure is a `Radians`, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

OK, there is one side case where it may be useful to know this, and that's if you're printing things out based on how you go them. So if the user gave you degree information to start, then you want to print everything in degrees (using a `description` method that you didn't mention). And maybe that's worth doing in that particular case.If you want to, your original code was very close:

```
func +(lhs: Angle, rhs: Angle) -> Angle {
    return lhs.dynamicType.init(rawRadians: lhs.rawRadians + rhs.rawRadians)
}
```

But it's critical to understand that this doesn't match your request to have "the lhs argument to dictate the return type." This causes the lhs argument to dictate the return *implementation*. The return *type* is always `Angle`. If you want to change the return *type*, you need to use the generics.

Comment: Awesome! That works. If you have a chance, I would be grateful if you added a bit of explanation in how the compiler interprets the generic part of the syntax there. I vaguely kind of understand generics, but not enough. Is <A> essentially a placeholder for any type that could there, and you constrain the acceptable maps via the `:Angle` part?

Comment: I spoke too early. I just discovered a problem with this. If I have two variables that are declared type `Angle`, not refined further to one of my three conforming structs, then the compiler says that `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied between two 'Angle' operands`